# label of selected row in gridview asp.net with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I would like to return text label in my gridview with Jquery

```
 <div class="risksContainer">
        <div class="risksGrid">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridViewRisks" runat="server" 
        [...]
        />
                <Columns> 
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="...">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="CodeProductColumn">
                                <asp:Label ID="IDRisk" runat="server" CssClass="IDRiskIndex" Text="<%# Item.ID_Risk %>" />
                                <asp:Repeater ID="LabelRepeatCodeProduct" runat="server"
                                [....]
                          </asp:Repeater>
                   </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

I try many solutions, but i don't know how i get the label Text of my selected row.
javascript :

```
function blabla(){
 var Id_risk = $(".risksContainer .risksGrid .IDRiskIndex").text();
 alert("Id_risk =" + Id_risk );
 return Id_risk ;
}
```

(this function start when i click on edit button in my row)

I get text of all rows in my gridview and not only my selected row.
I try with "parent, child, first, selected, rows[]... 
I am beginner and i'm desperate to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function blabla() 
  {
      // find gridview
      var gv = document.getElementById("<%=GridViewRisks.ID %>");

      // get row count
      var gvRowCount = gv.rows.length;
      var i = 1;
      for (i; i<= gvRowCount - 1; i++) 
      {
      // get label value from column 2
      alert(gv.rows[i].cells[2].childNodes[1].innerHTML);
      }
      return false;
  }
</script> 
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick=" blabla();return false;" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you set the selected row in code behind with `GridViewRisks.SelectedIndex = i`, you can set the CSS class of the selected row.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewRisks" runat="server" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="selectedRow">
```

Now you can use that class to get the correct row in jQuery.

```
var Id_risk = $(".selectedRow .IDRiskIndex").text();
```